# In vs re.search python

Tags: python, regex

I have a python 2.7 script which usually runs for hours, and I am now trying to optimize it. It has a lot of searches for strings, which represents the heavy part of computation. At the moment I am currently using `re.search('stringToFind', haystack)` to find substrings in longer strings. I am considering rewriting all expressions that do not contain regular expressions and use `in` instead. Almost all strings that are searched for are normal strings, ie contains no regular expressions.

I know that `in` uses a `contains` method to check substrings, but I have no clue how re.search works for strings that are non-re. How does re.search actually work? Would it really be more efficient to use in rather than re.search for substring in string comparision?

EDIT: To clarify I can give an example of currently running code:

```
if re.search('extern', variable):
    # Do something...
```

Could be replace by:

```
if 'extern' in variable:
    # Do  something...
```

Comment: what do you mean by `strings that are non-re`? An example would be better.

Comment: Which approach was faster in your timing tests?

Comment: I would fully expect `in` to be faster.

Comment: i posit that you're trying to optimize 0.1% of run time of your script down to 0.01%, and thus completely wasting your time.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: Usually regex engines are much more expensive than substring, why don't you time both versions and see which one runs faster ?

Comment: If your search string is a plain text string, and if you don't need any actual regex features (like [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)), then there is no reason to use a regex in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I am mostly searching for strings without regular expressions. Why I wrote it using re in the first place is a good question, but I felt that if they had a similar time complexity changing it would not matter.

@justsomebody I am using 2.7, not python3.

Comment: Tbh, I never actually thought of timing an example. It seemed so logical to check the implementation. From FMc's answer I found that using regex instead of in took 4 times longer time, which concludes the answer for me.

Comment: @Pphoenix let me `s/3/2/` that for you: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html :)

Comment: @justsomebody Thank you, it was interesting! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have commented, executing a regular expression search is inherently more complex than a simple substring search. Here's a very rough benchmark:

```
import timeit
import re
s = '0' * 1000 + 'foo' + '0' * 1000
rgx = re.compile(r'foo')
setup = 'from __main__ import s, rgx'
print timeit.timeit('"foo" in s', setup = setup)             # 0.745168924332
print timeit.timeit('rgx.search(s).group(0)', setup = setup) # 1.14249396324
```

But if your program runs for hours, I doubt that the source of the problem lies in such areas.

Comment: @myildirim The regex has to be simple; otherwise, a simple substring search wouldn't be a viable alternative, and the OP's question wouldn't make any sense -- unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I am actually not using real regular expressions, just checking occurences of normal strings. Added an update now showing some code.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I never actually thought of timing an example. It seemed so logical to just check the implementation. My values when timing had an even bigger difference, 0.88 vs 3.02. Replacing all unneccessary regex.